# Code doesn't continue after setting headers and downloading file

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, phpexcel

I have cake php index function which shows some graphs of orders. On this index view user is able to select dates from, to and once form is submitted the graphs of orders for selected date gets updated. Now i'm trying to implement another functionality, exporting data to excel, by adding simple select option to those two date selects.

The problem is that when you wan't to export Excel, you have to set headers and once you set header, code doesn't continuo as i want.

So here is my index function

```
public function index() {
        $orderData = $this->Order->getDashboardOrdersStatisticBetweenData();

        if ($this->request->is('post') || $this->request->is('put')) {
            $dateFrom = $this->request->data['orderSumDates']['date_from'];
            $dateTo = $this->request->data['orderSumDates']['date_to'];
            $orderData = $this->Order->getDashboardOrdersStatisticBetweenData($dateFrom, $dateTo);
            if ($this->request->data['orderSumDates']['export_type'] == 'export_excel') {
                $this->generateExcelFile($orderData, $dateFrom, $dateTo);
                die('Code never gets here, but file is downloaded');
            }
        }

        $this->set('orderStatistic', $orderData);
    }
```

And this is my generate excel file function

```
protected function generateExcelFile($orderData, $dateFrom, $dateTo) {
        header('Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="OrderReport'.$dateFrom.'-'.$dateTo.'.xlsx"');

        $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
        $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
        // Summary of report
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('A5', 'Total number of orders');
        // Some other stuff
        $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');
        $objWriter->save('php://output');

        header_remove('Content-type');
        header_remove('Content-Disposition');
    }
```

So the problem is if i select export_excel option, `$this->generateExcelFile` function gets executed and excel file is downloaded, but then rest of the code never happens, like for example this `die('Code never gets here, but file is downloaded');` which i wan't to be executed. I have done some testing and if i comment out header() part of `$this->generateExcelFile` function, the code continuous normally (die gets executed), but excel file is not properly generate, so those headers are crucial. Can you please help me over come my problems.

Comment: Are errors enabled? Did you check error logs ?

Comment: There are no errors... The code is working, the problem is that is written wrong way. Once you set headers inside generateExcelFile function you will not continuo in index function

Comment: Try executing the code before returning the headers

Comment: If code is not executed, it's probably that an error happens somewhere, or that the code is explicitely stopped. In your function, would you like to try to return the $objWritter instead of showing it. And you can display it from your controller, (and set headers after the PHPExcel instance is created)

Comment: @TedRed can you please share example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could save that Excel file, then send it to the browser using Cakephp built in functions.

1 - Create a folder `files` on your `TMP` folder

```
app/tmp/files
```

2- Save the file generated on that folder on your function, and return the file location

```
protected function generateExcelFile($orderData, $dateFrom, $dateTo) {
    //header('Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel'); // REMOVE THIS LINE
    //header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="OrderReport' . $dateFrom . '-' . $dateTo . '.xlsx"'); // REMOVE THIS LINE

    $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
    // Summary of report
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('A5', 'Total number of orders');
    // Some other stuff
    $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');

    $tmpFile = TMP . "files" . DS . sprintf("excel-file-%s.xlsx", date('Y-m-d-H-i-s')); // The tmp file
    $objWriter->save($tmpFile); // Save on excel file
    return $tmpFile; //send the file location

    //$objWriter->save('php://output'); // REMOVE THIS LINE

    //header_remove('Content-type'); // REMOVE THIS LINE
    //header_remove('Content-Disposition'); // REMOVE THIS LINE
}
```

3- On your action, send that file content to the browser after deleting this file

```
public function index() {
    $orderData = $this->Order->getDashboardOrdersStatisticBetweenData();

    if ($this->request->is('post') || $this->request->is('put')) {
        $dateFrom = $this->request->data['orderSumDates']['date_from'];
        $dateTo = $this->request->data['orderSumDates']['date_to'];
        $orderData = $this->Order->getDashboardOrdersStatisticBetweenData($dateFrom, $dateTo);
        if ($this->request->data['orderSumDates']['export_type'] == 'export_excel') {
            $excelFile = $this->generateExcelFile($orderData, $dateFrom, $dateTo);
            //Get the file content
            $content = file_get_contents($excelFile);
            //Delete that file
            unlink($excelFile);
            //Put the content on the response
            $this->response->body($content);
            //Force download (test.xlsx is the file name browser will recieve)
            $this->response->download("test.xlsx");
            //spécify the response type
            $this->response->type("application/vnd.ms-excel");
            //send the response
            return $this->response;
        }
    }

    $this->set('orderStatistic', $orderData);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! At the end i didn't do it exact same as you did, but you give me some good guiding lines! ;)